# Dialogs handled from CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

The doubt I have is conceptual.
Activity A holds Fragment B. Fragment B has a list view which is filled by a custom adapter. Each item from the adapter has a checkbox which onChecked true should display a AlertDialog to allow users to choose a item. My question is, should this interaction with the dialog ( and its different listeners (onClick, onCancel, onKey, etc) ) be handled by the holder class of each item, by the adapter class, the fragment or the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap your AlertDialog with DialogFragment instead of using pure AlertDialog, so it will handle dialog recreation on configuration change for you. Now, the interactions from this dialog should be passed back to activity I assume, for this I'd create an interface and make your activity to implement it. And lastly in the DialogFragment#onAttach cast your activity to this interface and hold this reference in some field, once user done any interactions, use this reference to safely pass data back to activity, or any other client, implementing this interface. Hope this makes sense.